# Getting Blank page on localhost:3000 while using npm along with reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, localhost

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H08iU.png)

```
    var express = require ('express');

//create our app
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(3000,function(){

  console.log('Sever is up  on port 3000');

});
```

This is code of Server.js file.

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/6.1.19/browser.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.4.1/react-dom.js"></script>

  </head>

<body>

  <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Code of index.html file

---

```
var Greeter = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return(
    <div>
      <h1> Howdy! </h1>
    </div>
    );
}
});


ReactDOM.render(
<Greeter/>,
  document.getElementbyId('app')
);
```

Code of app.jsx file

where is error? i don't find any error.
But when I am opening http://localhost:3000, I am getting a blank page.
Am using Windows 10 and node -v 6.9.1

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: There is no element with `id="app"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **babel 5.8.23**.

You forgot to put in the `app` HTML element.

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

Also, there's a typo in `getElementById`. The **`B`** should be caps.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Greeter/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add html element with `id='app'`, Include this in html file, it will work.

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

There is an error in this part:

```
ReactDOM.render(
     <Greeter/>,
     document.getElementbyId('app')
);
```

check the spelling of `getElementbyId`, instead of that put this `getElementById`.

Comment: i added <div id="app"></div> but still same issue.

Comment: m still getting blank page , i tried your all possible solutions but still getting blank page.

Comment: see this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kwqvkj4y/ frontend is working, one more try put some `<p>Hello</p>` in your html body and see whether that is coming or not, to confirm the problem is at which part, server or some react issue.

Comment: i'd tried that also. it not working with solutions. Still at the same error.

Comment: did that hello world appear in the page ?

Comment: No. Hello world didn't appear.

Comment: if you tried this: 
`<body>
  <p>Hello</p>
    <script type="text/babel" src="app.jsx"></script>
</body>` and hello is not coming then there is some issue at backend side, please check your code, whether you are returning html page page properly or not.

Comment: YES this hello is printing on front page.

Comment: did you included this in ur html page?  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.19.0/babel.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Not Happening with <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone‌​/6.19.0/babel.min.js‌​"></script>

Answer (score 0):

continued to the answer by @MayankShukla. Try adding script for babel transpiler to transform jsx code, include this reference:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.19.0/babel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update a Div with id as app since React is not able find an Div with id *app*

```
<div id="app"/>
```

Comment: did you check your Developer Console ? Are you getting any Error ?

Comment: var Greeter = React.createClass({

  render: function(){
    return(
    <div>
       FARHAN
    </div>
    );
}
});
ReactDOM.render(
<Greeter/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
in above code the first line React.createClass({}) having some issue of declaring fuciton()